# Oracle XML functions with large datasets

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, format, size

I have problems to use the Oracle XML functions like

`xmlelement`, `xmlagg`, `xmlattributes`

For instance:

```
select 
 XMLELEMENT(
 "OrdrList",
      XMLAGG(
        XMLELEMENT(
        "IDs",
            XMLATTRIBUTES(
            USERCODE AS "usrCode",
            VALDATE AS "validityDate"
            )
        )
     )   
 ) from TMP
/
```

The code seems to be correct as it does work when returning a small number of messages

And yes, I did try to set "long", "pagesize", "linesize" etc... but have never been able to retrieve the full set of approx. 500.000 XML-messages (i.e. table rows).

Reading some background literature (e.g. "Oracle SQL" by Jürgen Sieben) it seems that the functions are not designed for large data sets. Mr. Sieben explains that he uses these only for small queries (max. 1 MB output size), above that he recommends to use "object-oriented functions" but does not explain which.

Does somebody have experience with this and has the above XML-functions working or knows alternatives?

---

As per advice below: converting to CLOB through [...]`.getclobval(0, 2) from TMP` iterates now through the whole table. <s>Slow, but complete.</s>

---

I have to make a **correction**: `getclobval` delivers a longer but still not complete list. 
As my confidence in the implementation/documentation quality of the above Oracle XML functions is weak, I will create a standard file-output from the database and implement the XML-conversion myself.

---

**New update: I found the culprit: `XMLAGG`!** If I take it out, the database is speedily, properly, stepwise and completely parsed. Strange since XMLAGG does not really have a complicated job: creating an ingoing and outgoing XML-tag

Comment: Can you please be more specific?  What errors are you getting?  What environment is the select being executed from, sqlplus?

Comment: I'm runnning sqlplus/Oracle 11g - both from command line and inside the Visual Studio 2010 editor. I'm getting no errors, the output is truncated after approx. 1500 XML-messages ("**ID**"-elements, see above) from overall 300.000. (there are a few more minor things: strange linebreaks, superflous white spaces, but those I could fix)

Comment: Generally I think that sqlplus generates the XML output as a single object instead of parsing the database successively. I.e. if you run a simple SELECT on the database the output is processed and written out record by record. If I run the above code, however, there is a time of about 10 seconds were nothing happens and then the output is written more or less at once. So I think the limitation is related to how sqlplus creates the XML object. If this is true Oracle should document it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think showing this data in sqlplus + spool completely is going to be a struggle.

I have used these functions for > 100Mb of data without problems, but I have written the returned XMLType out to files after converting to CLOB, using either UTL_FILE for server side or in client apps in Java/C#.

If you are stuck with sqlplus, have you tried it with "SET TERM OFF" and spool? It might give better results, would certainly be quicker. Note to use SET TERM OFF you have to be careful how you invoke sqlplus; sqlplus @script will work, but "cat <

Comment: SET TERM OFF and SPOOL into a file do not bring any difference. I will try CLOB/UTIL_FILE.